# Repeated use of map on extract of nested data fails

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I've come up against a problem with my R script using purrr that I don't quite understand and I'm hoping someone here can enlighten me.

Here's an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

rep_raw <- tbl_df(iris) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(values = map(data, "Sepal.Length"),
         mean = map(values, mean),
         mean_sepal = map(values, mean)) %>%
  glimpse
```

Gives me the following output

```
Observations: 3
Variables: 5
$ Species    <fct> setosa, versicolor, virginica
$ data       <list> [<tbl_df[50 x 4]>, <tbl_df[50 x 4]>, <tbl_df[50 x 4]>]
$ values     <list> [<5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0, 5.4, 4.6, 5.0, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8, 4.8, 4.3, 5.8, 5.7, 5.4, 5.1, 5.7, 5.1, 5.…
$ mean       <list> [5.006, 5.936, 6.588]
$ mean_sepal <list> [NULL, NULL, NULL]
```

Why is it that the first calculation 'mean' works and the second calculation 'mean_sepal' gives NULL values?

I expected mean and mean_sepal to be identical.

Comment: Isn't this just a scoping issue? When you use `mean` as a column name, `map` thinks you're calling `mean` the column, not `mean`, the function. If you rename the `mean` column to `mean2`, `mean_sepal` calculates fine.

Comment: This means that in your code, the column `mean` is calculated fine, because there is no conflict, but for `mean_sepal` you now have a column called `mean`, which creates ambiguity.

Comment: Explanation from @Mako212 makes sense but it is also strange that this is not an issue with `lapply`, `tbl_df(iris) %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(values = map(data, "Sepal.Length"),
           mean = lapply(values, mean), mean2 = lapply(values, mean))` gives you expected values.

Comment: Ahhhh of course thanks very much @Mako212, that explains that!

Comment: @RonakShah my guess (without diving deeply into the documentation/source code) is that this is due to the `tidyverse` support for unquoted column names, and that the `.f` argument of `map` will take a "function, formula, or vector" as its value. By contrast, `lapply` requires `FUN` to be a function

Comment: If you try to pass `c(1,2,3)` to `FUN` in `lapply` you get the error: `'c(1, 2, 3)' is not a function, character or symbol`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `mean_sepal` doesn't calculate correctly is that you have a scoping issue. `mean` typically calls the function `mean()` which takes the average of values. However, you've thrown a wrench into this by naming your new column `mean`. This forces `map` to to make a choice to reference the vector `mean`, or call the function `mean()`.

The `.f` argument in `map` can be assigned to a "function, formula, or vector", per the documentation, and because of that, `mean` the vector is a valid input.

As @RonakShah noted in the comments, we don't have this same issue with `lapply`. I believe this is because `lapply` requires `FUN` to be a function (or mathematical symbol) and so in contrast to `map`, the vector `mean` is not a valid value for `FUN`.

We see here, if we pass a vector to `FUN`, `lapply` returns an error.

```
lapply(c(4,3), FUN = c(1,2,3))
```

> Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
>         'c(1, 2, 3)' is not a function, character or symbol